# Draggable and sortable, stop and update events

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm working with the draggable class and the sortable class from Jquery UI. My draggable in connected with my sortable and I need to transfer from my draggable container to my sortable container.

In my draggable container I have 2 different items, lets say it is an article and a book and my sortable container is the bookshelf. This is what I am trying to do: when a book is dragged into the bookshelf, it is added on there; but if an article is dragged on to a bookshelf, a book is created in the article is added to the book. This is because only books are allowed on the bookshelf.

I have been able to identify which initiates which functions with a simple if/else if in javascript and I attach this ito my stop Event in the draggable container. it all works fine up to here. The problem is that the stop event doesn't detect when it is placed in the sortable container, so if I move it around the screen and release the mouse button somewhere else, the stop event still executes and carries on with what should happen when it is on the actual container.

I have also tried placing these functions in the update event of the sortable container, but when I do this, for some reason the steps don't execute and, even though it places it visually over the sortable, it doesn't save, or do the rest of the actual functionality.

**update:**

$(".draggableUnselected").draggable({

```
    cursor: 'pointer',
    connectToSortable: "##bookShelf",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid",
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
        if($(this).attr("itemType")=="Book")
            {updateSelectedBooks();}
        else if($(this).attr("itemType")=="article")
            {
            $.ajax({
                url : "/com/Book.cfc",
                data : { method: 'quickAddBook', organizationid: #iterator.organizationid()#, profileid: #url.id#, name: "New Book "+$(this).attr("articleName") },
                error : statusAjaxError,
                dataType : "text",
                cache: false
            });
            updateSelectedBooks();
            }
        }
```

});

var $selectedBooks = $("##selectedBooks ");

```
        $selectedBooks .sortable({
            revert: true,
            placeholder: "bookShelfTarget",
            connectWith: "##recycling"//,
           // update: //I copy the code from stop here for debugging
        });
```

Comment: Can you include a fiddle for demonstration purposes?

Comment: I updated some code in my question, I can't include a fiddle at this moment. The extra # symbols are due to integration with coldfusion.

Comment: Without fiddle or HTML code it's pretty hard to help you :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this after doing some research and the answer was actually to use my code inside the revert and not stop or update. using another if to identify if the object was released out of the container.

revert: function (socketObj)

```
            {
                if (socketObj) 
                {
                   //code goes here
                }
             return !socketObj;
            }
```